# Detect AJAX request in OpenCart Controller

Tags: ajax, controller, request, opencart, opencart-3

I´m working on some controllers in OpenCart 3 and I want one of the controller functions only to be accessible through AJAX request.
I tried with $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] variable but OC says that the variable is undefined.

Best Regards

pcosta94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually OpenCart doesn't remove the $_SERVER vars. It just passes them to $this->server. The issue is that 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' is only set if there was an AJAX call. Otherwise, it will give an error.

you can test if any of your requests have been made via AJAX by adding this code to file `system/library/request.php` on `line 32`

after `$this->server = $this->clean($_SERVER);` add:

```php
if(isset($this->server['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    echo '<script>console.log(' . json_encode($this->server['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) .')</script>';
}
```

then open your OpenCart frontend and visit any product page and you should see in your Browser console `XMLHttpRequest`

like so
http://joxi.ru/MAjo6vWTjZZjBr

> this is because on the product page the reviews are loaded via AJAX. On homepage there are no AJAX calls, so you shouldn't see anything in the console.

I hope this helps.